# How to force increment of primary key when an empty string is provided?

Tags: php, sqlite, pdo

Query :

```
$query = 'INSERT INTO `menu` (`id`,`name`,`value`) VALUES (:id,:name,:value);';
```

Parameters array :

```
$params = [':id' => '', ':name' => 'John', ':value' => 'ABC'];
```

`id` is a `PRIMARY KEY` and `AUTOINCREMENT` column. In MySQL `id` column is autoincremented even if value passed is an empty string `''`. This does not apply to SQLite since an error is thrown :

```
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 20 datatype mismatch
```

How to force SQLite to increment the primary key field when an empty string is provided?

Background from [documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/autoinc.html) :

> On an INSERT, if the ROWID or INTEGER PRIMARY KEY column is not explicitly given a value, then it will be filled automatically with an unused integer, usually one more than the largest ROWID currently in use.

and :

> If no ROWID is specified on the insert, or if the specified ROWID has a value of NULL, then an appropriate ROWID is created automatically.

Comment: `$query = 'INSERT INTO menu ('name','value') VALUES (:name,:value);';` and `$params = [':name' => 'John', ':value' => 'ABC'];`

Comment: @A-2-A yes, I am aware of this. Still I would like to keep the empty string param.

Comment: That is not possible because it is `primary` and `auto-incremented` column. `primary` keys not accepting null values.

Comment: `''` will treated as null when it comes to db query execution. I think so

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should either pass `null` for the `auto_increment` field or not specify it at all. For mysql passing an empty string works under certain configuration settings only and works because mysql silently converts the empty string to `0`, so you should not rely on it or expect any other rdbms to follow suit.

See mysql's documentation on [no_auto_value_on_zero sql mode](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_no_auto_value_on_zero) for details:

> NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO affects handling of AUTO_INCREMENT columns.
> Normally, you generate the next sequence number for the column by
> inserting either NULL or 0 into it. NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO suppresses
> this behavior for 0 so that only NULL generates the next sequence
> number.